# How to wake up thread after [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] runMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode beforeDate:distantFuture]?

Tags: objective-c, nsurlconnection, nsthread, nsoperation, nsrunloop

I have a **Download** object which handles **NSURLConnection**.

Then I have **NSOperation** object (**DownloadOperation**) which holds **Download** object as property.

**Download** object has ability to *start/pause/resume/cancel*.

This is the main method of **DownloadOperation**

```
- (void)main
{
    @autoreleasepool {

        BOOL isDone = NO;

        if (![self isCancelled]) {   
            [_download start]; //Download object start (creates NSURLConnection internally)
        }

        NSDate *distantFuture = [NSDate distantFuture];
        while(!isDone && ![self isCancelled]) {

            [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] runMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode beforeDate:distantFuture];

            if (!_download.isActive) { //internal state of Download
                isDone = YES;
            }
        }

        [self completeOperation]; //this sets finished and executing flags
    }
}
```

From outside (from UI), I manipulate with **Download** object: *Start*, *Pause*, *Resume*, *Cancel*.
And internally I am changing its state so when **Download** is finished or canceled, *isActive* is set to **NO** and while loop should end.

This works if I start **Download** and let it finish (in background, **NSURLConnection** finished and called delegate -*connectionDidFinish*...)

If I *pause/resume* **Download**, download will continue to download and finish (and change its internal state: *isActive* -> **NO**).
On pause I cancel **NSURLConnection** and on resume I create new.

Or if I *cancel* the download, it will also be inactive (**NSURLConnection** is canceled).

But here is the problem:

`[[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] runMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode beforeDate:distantFuture];` never returns in those cases (when I cancel **NSURLConnection**) and my "*if*" statement is never handled so this **DownloadOperation** is always considered running and will never exit my **NSOperationQueue**.

It looks like there is no event that could be fired that would cause that runloop to wake up.

I tried

```
            [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] runMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode beforeDate:[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:0.05]];
```

and this kind of works but not so smooth and I don't think it is the best solution.

What I really want to know is, how to force that **NSRunLoop** to wake up (how to fire some event that will cause it to wake up) and continue my while loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's what I did.

Good thing is that I have notifications in my app and I know exactly when downloads are changing. So I've made an instance variable `NSThread currentThread` and at the beginning of main I call `currentThread = [NSThread currentThread]`.

After I receive notification which I know should cause my thread to wake up I call:

`[self performSelector:@selector(wakeUpThread:) onThread:currentThread withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];`

`- (void)wakeUpThread` does nothing, it is empty method, but purpose of this is to wake up thread and cause my run loop to continue.